# How to change the height dynamically according to screen size?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a RelativeLayout with a ViewPager and another LinearLayout. I have set the layout width of the ViewPager as `match_parent` and have given the layout height a fixed value of 250dp.

However, when changing the screen sizes bigger and bigger, the height of the ViewPager gets smaller.

How to make the height change according to screen size?

If I set the height to `wrap_content` it almost takes up the whole screen except for a smaller bit reserved for the other layout.

The code is posted below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.sloid.destinations.navigationdrawerfragments.aboutSLFragment">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why you have set it android:layout_height="250dp" ... any reason?

Comment: you can use dimens property.. also ..set different dimensions for different screen sizes.. if at all you must have to set a fixed screen size..

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

If you want to make your screen design for multiple devices ,

You can use **WeightSum** with **LinearLayout** as **Container** to avoid this like below :-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context="com.example.sloid.destinations.navigationdrawerfragments.aboutSLFragment">


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3.5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6.5"
/>



</LinearLayout>
```

for reference :-https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

Comment: Thunder I cannot use layoutWeight because I need to add a scrollView.Is there any other way to do that.And if I used layoutWeights and added a scrollview as the parent view, it works except for a tiny probleem.Can you fix that. The link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849507/images-disappear-when-read-more-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 0):

You could also use modern new ConstraintLayout https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html
to set percentage of viewpager view relative to screen height (33% in example below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/SliderDots"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewPager"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hello Deni this answer makes the dot indicators go down and this is not what I expected.Anyway using layoutWeight fixed the problem but a problem arises when the whole code is added insidde a scrollView.Can you have a look and give your opinion.link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849507/images-disappear-when-read-more-button-is-clicked

Comment: I have multiple siblings, Better solution would be to set the height as a percentage of full screen height.

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer your question :

> How to make the height change according to screen size?

You can externalize your height value to the dimens.xml in the default values folder, like

```
<dimen name="view_pager_height">250dp</dimen>
```

and in the values-sw720dp folder you can put

```
 <dimen name="view_pager_height">300dp</dimen>
```

Then use it in the layout like this:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/view_pager_height"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
```

Read more about that here: [Using new size qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers).

Besides that, you can use a [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) as a parent, and set weights to each child. (RelativeLayouts as parents are quite expensive, as they double measure their children)

Answer (score 0):

Set **viewpager** to be above **sliderdots**.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context="com.example.sloid.destinations.navigationdrawerfragments.aboutSLFragment">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
android:id="@+id/viewPager" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_above="@+id/SliderDots"/> 
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/SliderDots" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```