# Images disappear when read more button is clicked?

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, android-layout-weight

I created a ScrollView and added two LinearLayouts inside one big LinearLayout and have given weights for those.The problem is that it shows my images of the image slider at initial state and once I clicked read more the images dissapear except for the dot indicators.Once again when I press read less the images of the image slider appear.Two screenshots and the codes are given below.How can I solve it?

FragmentSL.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4.5"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5.5"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aboutsltext"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:text="Sri Lanka (formerly Ceylon) is an island nation south of India in the Indian Ocean. Its diverse landscapes range from rainforest and arid plains to highlands and sandy beaches. It’s famed for its ancient Buddhist ruins, including the 5th-century citadel Sigiriya, with its palace and frescoes. The city of Anuradhapura, Sri Lanka's ancient capital, has many ruins dating back more than 2,000 years. Sri Lanka (formerly Ceylon) is an island nation south of India in the Indian Ocean. Its diverse landscapes range from rainforest and arid plains to highlands and sandy beaches. It’s famed for its ancient Buddhist ruins, including the 5th-century citadel Sigiriya, with its palace and frescoes. The city of Anuradhapura, Sri Lanka's ancient capital, has many ruins dating back more than 2,000 years. "
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readmorebtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Read More"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:background="@drawable/readmorebtn"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

FragmentClass.java

public class aboutSLFragment extends Fragment{

```
ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;
TextView aboutsltext;
Button readmorebtn;

public aboutSLFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView .findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getContext());

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

        dots[i] = new ImageView(getContext());
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

    }

    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.non_active_dot));
            }

            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    aboutsltext=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutsltext);
    readmorebtn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.readmorebtn);
    readmorebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (readmorebtn.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Read More"))
            {
                aboutsltext.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);//your TextView
                readmorebtn.setText("Read Less");
            }
            else
            {
                aboutsltext.setMaxLines(3);//your TextView
                readmorebtn.setText("Read More");
            }
        }
    });

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("About Sri Lanka");
}

}
```

**before read more is clicked**
[before read more button is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K68S.jpg)

**after**
[after clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5626.png)

Calculating code

```
   final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_sl, container, false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView .findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    ViewTreeObserver vto =(ViewTreeObserver) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutslscrollview).getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutslscrollview).getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            int scrollViewHeightInPixels = rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutslscrollview).getMeasuredHeight();

            //This is equal with %45 weight you tried before
            int height = (scrollViewHeightInPixels * 45) / 100;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams pagerParams = viewPager.getLayoutParams();
            pagerParams.height = height;
        }
    });


    final View view = rootView.findViewById(R.id.aboutslscrollview);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = view.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            int scrollViewHeightInPixels = view.getMeasuredHeight();

            //This is equal with %45 weight you tried before
            int height = (scrollViewHeightInPixels * 45) / 100;
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams pagerParams = viewPager.getLayoutParams();
            pagerParams.height = height;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Giving vertical weight inside Scrollview is not make sense. Weight should be used when height/width is fixed. In scrollview, height is not fixed as you know. What do you want to achieve? Can you add an image for visualization, what's on your mind?

Comment: I posted pictures of that. I want the layout to be like on image one and after i clicked on read more button it should show a scrollable view with both image and text and not like that on image two. I used layoutWeight because it changes height according to screensizes

Comment: Is there any way to change the height accordingly without using weights

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented before, your logic **will not work properly**, because giving vertical weight inside a `ScrollView` causes calculation problems.

So you should not use need any **weight** to resize your `ViewPager` content width.

If you have certain width/height ratio, resize it programmatically like below. Write these lines inside of **onCreate()**, after `findViewById`:

> **UPDATE** You can get scrollView height like this :

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

ViewTreeObserver vto = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
   scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        int scrollViewHeightInPixels = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

        //This is equal with %45 weight you tried before
        int height = (scrollViewHeightInPixels * 45) / 100;
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams pagerParams = viewPager.getLayoutParams();
        pagerParams.height = height;
    } 
});
```

Then remove unnecessary layouts and change your layout like below:

> 200 dp on viewPager height is for fixed height at start, wrap_content and match_parent sometimes causes problems

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/viewPager"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />


        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aboutsltext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Sri Lanka (formerly Ceylon) is an island nation south of India in the Indian Ocean. Its diverse landscapes range from rainforest and arid plains to highlands and sandy beaches. It’s famed for its ancient Buddhist ruins, including the 5th-century citadel Sigiriya, with its palace and frescoes. The city of Anuradhapura, Sri Lanka's ancient capital, has many ruins dating back more than 2,000 years. Sri Lanka (formerly Ceylon) is an island nation south of India in the Indian Ocean. Its diverse landscapes range from rainforest and arid plains to highlands and sandy beaches. It’s famed for its ancient Buddhist ruins, including the 5th-century citadel Sigiriya, with its palace and frescoes. The city of Anuradhapura, Sri Lanka's ancient capital, has many ruins dating back more than 2,000 years. "
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/readmorebtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/readmorebtn"
            android:text="Read More"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hello Oguzhan, I am new to android, may I know where in the class i should add your code(the exact position on oncreate).I have posted my code above so can you say me where to place it. And also may I know if the height changes according to screen sizes why have you set the height of the ViewPager to 200dp

Comment: @Chana hi, updated the answer, you can ask anything if you have any questions about the answer.

Comment: Hello Oguzhan now I understood why you have set the height of VewPager to 200 dp and now the problem is where on code should I paste the height calculation code. Can you tell me the exact location

Comment: Bro Oguzhan, I copied and pasted the oncreate codes under finderViewById. But it give and error here(scrollViewHeightInPixels) saying that cannot resolve symbol 'scrollViewHeightInPixels' and same goes to the other code saying cannot resolve symbol 'screenWidthInPixels'. what should i do now?

Comment: @Chana You must get your scrollview height programmatically, "scrollViewHeightInPixels" is variable name to understand. You must place your scrollview height instead of this. Updated the answer.

Comment: sorry bro another error occurs.The thing is i am new to android,so i get nervous.please don't mind that. The error is in the calculating heightcode. ViewTreeObserver vto = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver(); In here it says cannot resolve symbol 'scrollView' and the other error is in int scrollViewHeightInPixels = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); the layout is in red and it says Qualifier must be and expression.Please help me bro

Comment: @Chana That is another basic topics of Android. You need to use findViewById, set your scrollview an ID on xml layout, and get your scrollview, just like you did for ViewPager before. If I write these all, I need to write all of your codes form scratch. You need to figure it out by yourself.

Comment: Bro Oguzhan I added two codes that i think might be correct.Can you check that and say what''s correct and if there are error can you tell me how to fix it